# Filtering NA values when loop goes outside vector (defining loop boundaries)

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, trading

I am running two nested for loops to check, on every row of a vector, if any of the 10 rows below is 3 points greater than 3 rows further below. If true, a 1 is recorded on a newly created binary vector. (sounds convoluted I know, but comparisons of this sort allow to test conditions in time series for trading purposes)

For example, for row one, want to check if:

- row 2 > row 5 + 3 OR
- row 3 > row 6 + 3 OR

  ...
- row 11 > row 14 + 3

(BTW I need the loops, idea is to run this on thousands of rows, not just 20)

The following code works well, but has the unwanted characteristic of producing NA values when one of the loop goes outside the vector.

```
df <- data.frame(  LastPrice = c( 1221, 1220, 1230, 1217, 1216,  1218 , 1216, 1216, 1217, 1220, 1219, 1218, 1220, 1216, 1217, 1218, 1218, 1207, 1206, 1205))

df$StrongMoveBinary[j] <- 0
for(j in 1:20) {
  tmp <- 0
  for (i in 1:10) { 
    tmp <- tmp + ifelse (df$LastPrice[j+i] - df$LastPrice[j+i+3] > 3, 1, 0)}
  df$StrongMoveBinary[j] <- tmp>0}

//Note: purpose of tmp variable is to record every occasion that LastPrice > LastPrice 3 rows below, rather than just the last instance
```

That code creates **StrongMoveBinary = 1  1  0  0  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA**. That's 13 NAs. But there is sufficient data to have only 4 NAs. The other 9 NAs are a result of poor coding from my part. To get around the issue I modified the code, to restrict the values of "i" given the values of "j", hence stopping the "i" loop to loop outside the vector.

```
df$StrongMoveBinary[j] <- 0
for(j in 1:20) {
  x <- 0
  if (j <= 10) {x=10}
  if (j > 10) {x=20-j}
  tmp <- 0
  for (i in 1:x) { 
    tmp <- tmp + ifelse (df$LastPrice[j+i] - df$LastPrice[j+i+3] > 3, 1, 0)}
  df$StrongMoveBinary[j] <- tmp>0}
```

Unfortunately it is not working. StrongMoveBinary still has 13 NAs. Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: So, when you say "any of the 10 rows below", it's more like "*any of up to 10 rows below (fewer if there aren't enough rows)....*" Is that right? So by the time we get to row 16, you check if row 17 > row 20, then for row 17 an `NA` is the correct response, yes?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I tried in the modified code. For row 18 NA is the correct response. Row 17 still can be calculated.

Comment: How can row 17 be calculated? In your example, "**For row 1**", the comparisons go from row 2 > row 5 to row 11 > row 14. By this logic, "**For row 17**", we add 16 to all those numbers and get from row 18 > row 21 *which does not exist* - not even the first comparison. Please correct either the example or the comment.

Comment: You are correct. My prior comment was wrong. Rows 17 to 20 must be NAs. Thank you!

Comment: One last question. In your code you check if the difference between rows is `> 3`. But in your text you just say 
"*row 2 is greater than row 5*". Do you care if row 2 is greater than row 5, or if row 5 - row 2 > 3?

Comment: My apologies. Need to edit it again. Care about row 5 - row 2 > 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest problem confusion is due to the lack of named variables. You have several parameters (look *3 rows below*, if any of *10 rows below*, the number of rows in the data frame, how much of a difference to check for) but you are just using numbers all over, which is hard to keep straight. You shouldn't write `20`, you should write `nrow(df)` - this way the same code works on your 20-row example and your thousands-of-rows real data. And if any parameters change, you can make the change in one place only.

```
window = 10     # up to this far below the current row
rows_below = 3  # check against this far down
min_diff = 3    # for a difference at least this big
```

Now we will use these to explicitly calculate the bounds of the loop. `pmin` is a really handy function for making sure we don't go outside the bounds of the data. (These definitions, of course, should be checked very carefully for accuracy - this is what I was doing when I wrote those nitpicky comments about whether or not the 17th entry should be `NA` or not.)

```
base_rows = 1:(nrow(df) - rows_below - 1)  # can't check more than this

# for a given base row, this is the maximum row to start checking against
candidate_max = pmin(base_rows + window, nrow(df) - rows_below)

# pre-allocate a vector of results
StrongMoveBinary = integer(length = length(base_rows))
```

With all that set up, we're ready to test:

```
for (i in seq_along(base_rows)) {
    StrongMoveBinary[i] = as.numeric(
        any(
            df$LastPrice[(i + 1):candidate_max[i]] - 
                df$LastPrice[((i + 1):candidate_max[i]) + rows_below] > min_diff
        )
    )
}
```

And let's see what we've got:

```
StrongMoveBinary
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I've left off the `NA`s entirely. If you'd rather have them, pre-allocate `StrongMoveBinary = rep(NA, nrow(df))` instead of the way I did it at the top.

---

In the end, maybe we'd want to turn this into a function that can be applied to any vector. It's pretty easy with the parameters set up. The only edits are making it work on a vector (with `length()`) instead of a specific row of a data frame (with `nrow()`).

```
strong_indicate = function(x, window = 10, rows_below = 3, min_diff = 3) {
    base_rows = 1:(length(x) - rows_below - 1)  # can't check more than this

    # for a given base row, this is the maximum row to start checking against
    candidate_max = pmin(base_rows + window, length(x) - rows_below)

    # pre-allocate a vector of results
    StrongMoveBinary = integer(length = length(base_rows))

    for (i in seq_along(base_rows)) {
        StrongMoveBinary[i] = as.numeric(
            any(
                x[(i + 1):candidate_max[i]] - 
                    x[((i + 1):candidate_max[i]) + rows_below] > min_diff
            )
        )
    }
    return(StrongMoveBinary)
}
```

We can call it on the column of data:

```
strong_indicate(x = df$LastPrice)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And we can explore what other values would do:

```
strong_indicate(x = df$LastPrice, min_diff = 12)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

strong_indicate(x = df$LastPrice, window = 5)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Truly impressive. You have no idea how much I appreciate this response. Thank you!!!

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that, while it works and it's relatively clean, it's still *terribly* inefficient because we calculate each row difference every time we need it. That is row 11 - row 14 is calculated for the first row, then again for the second row, and again... 10 times. A better way would be to calculate all the differences and compare them to `min_diff` once, store that in a vector, and then use that vector to calculate the final result. If this is too slow for your data, ask another question about how to speed it up and we can work on it there.

Comment: Will do, thanks a lot! The window can easily be 1500 rows, so I expect it to be madly slow. One step at a time. Need to process this first and put it to practice.